# handle child components event inside parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

in reactjs i want to determine best practice solution, so i have a parent component called Main. and i also have child component called Form. this is Main:

```
<Form 
    adminname={this.state.adminname}
    password={this.state.password}
    Input={this.handleInput}
    Submit={this.handleForm}
    error={this.props.error}
/>
```

and this is child component Form

```
<div className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={this.props.Submit} className="formc" action="/api/sign-in" method="POST">
            <input type="text" className="adminname" name="adminname" placeholder="Administrator" value={this.props.adminname} onChange={this.props.Input} />
            <input type="password" className="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value={this.props.password} onChange={this.props.Input} />
            <input type="submit" className="submitbtn" value="Sign In"/>
            {this.props.error ? <h3 className="error">{this.props.error}</h3> : null}
        </form>
</div>
```

and should i add this code

```
handleInput(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
handleForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let dataToPass ={
        adminname: this.state.adminname,
        password: this.state.password
    }
    this.props.signin(dataToPass)
}
```

to  Main or to Form? which one is best practice

(By the way i am using react-redux)

Comment: using functions in parent component is the best practice up to my knowledge because you can reuse the changed data to other child components or on the main page

Comment: I only use this form for Main.js

Comment: Then it depends on you. Actually I work in this way, all my functions and javascript actions will be on a dedicated hook if the data is to be reused. Otherwise, I use child components for calling functions

Comment: you can put both wherever you want, start with Form component and then move it up if your need arise in future in case other components are dependent on say it as submit handler.

Comment: pretty appropriate answer if you could post it as an answer and i will accept it